# how to find vowels from RDD in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to find the number vowels present in each words. I have written below code but I am not getting expected output. Can someone please help with below case

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("find vowel counnt").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext()
inputRDD=sc.textFile("file:///home/vikram/data/vowel.txt")

inputRDD.collect()

['vikram is best person']

flatRDD = inputRDD.flatMap(lambda x : x.split(" "))
flatRDD.collect()

['vikram', 'is', 'best', 'person']

vowels='aeiou'

def vowel_check(flatRDD, vowels):
    final=[x for x in flatRDD.collect() if x in vowels]
    print(len(final))
    print(final)

vowel_check(flatRDD,vowels)
```

Comment: Vikram -2 ,Is-1 , best -1,person -2

Comment: Output should be like word and vowels count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use regex `findall` and count. This performs the count and produces tuples of words with their vowel count:

```
import re
flatRDD.map(lambda l: (l, len(re.findall('[aeiou]', l)))).collect()
```

Producing:

```
[('vikram', 2), ('is', 1), ('best', 1), ('person', 2)]
```